# How to give select digit after decimal point?

Tags: sql

In database there is column amount which datatype is money. I want to select that row only with two digit after decimal. for this how to write the query?

My query is like this:

```
SELECT AMOUNT FROM DETAIL_PAGE.
```

I want to modify this query so that it selects two digits after decimal point.

Comment: The answer depend very much on which database you are using and how the AMOUNT column is defined in that database.

Comment: default it is coming with two decimal points rt?

Comment: @anishmarokey :default it come upto 4 decimal place in webpage using asp.net but in sql 2005 it come upto 2 decimal place

Comment: Formating the values inside the DB/SP is generally not advisable... If you are using ASP.NET try doing it the WebPage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT AMOUNT - FLOOR(AMOUNT) FROM DETAIL_PAGE
```

That will get you just the decimal though.  I think you want

```
SELECT FORMAT(AMOUNT, 2) FROM DETAIL_PAGE
```

Or without commas:

```
SELECT REPLACE(FORMAT(AMOUNT, 2), ',', '') FROM DETAIL_PAGE
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is SQL standard and works elsewhere, but in Oracle you can say

```
select round(amount,2) from detail_page

-- round(12.345, 2) would return 12.35
```

or

```
select trunc(amount,2) from detail_page

-- trunc(12.345, 2) would return 12.34
```